# jquery datepicker and indexed properties

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a struts form that contains many input fields generated using indexed properties.
As a result the id of my form elements are indexprop[0].date, indexprop[1].date etc.

Does anyone have any idea how i could assign a jquery datepicker to each of these input fields?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but this could be a start:

```
$("input[id$=.date]").datepicker( ... )
```

Comment: Philippe, your a legend. that worked very nicely.
I used it on the name attribute instead of id but it works very neatly.$('input[name$=.endDateFormatted]')

Thansk for helping me with this solution